# Is it normal for Android Studio taking so long to create new project?

Tags: plugins, android-studio, freeze

Im creating a new project in Android Studio and at the end when I click the final button, I get this window which has been currently sitting there for 5 minutes:

[image: Window takes a long time]

Ive read other posts but they are using Eclipse.  I found one about Android Studio but it was something about 32bit version.

Is this normal?  Im on mavericks & using Android Studio 0.4.3.

Wait, it started, 6 minutes into it and now the progress window at least shows activity, downloading something maven...done.

At the end i got a top right corner popup in red saying IDE error click for details.  And I get this from clicking on the bottom right corner red exclamation icon:

[image: Fatal IDE Error]

I reported to Google.  Should I disable the plugins (Android & Properties Support) or what else should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's normal. It's usually downloading Gradle, and possibly other project dependencies if there are any. It depends on your network speed. We're planning on providing more information at some point in the future because it's pretty confusing to get this dialog with no information about what's going on. That "already disposed" exception is https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65309